# What are the options of getting from Beyneu to Aktau in Kazakhstan?

Tags: hitchhiking, kazakhstan, shared-taxis, aktau

I'm going by train from Moscow to the Kazakh village of Beyneu. From there I'll either hitchhike **or** take a marshrukta to Aktau.

1. How easy is it to find a driver willing to take you to Aktau at 16:30 on a Friday, right after a train arrival?
2. What do marshrutkas from Beyneu to Aktau cost?

I've heard it's "a few dollars", not very helpful as the price is actually in tenge.

Comment: Please split this question into two: one about marshrutkas and one about money.

Comment: There's a train to Aktau (just please don't take obshi class, I'm speaking [from experience](http://www.marksmayo.com/2012/06/29/the-adventure-that-is-obshi-class-train-travel/))

Comment: Related (unanswered) [forum post](http://caravanistan.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1580) on Caravanistan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There's](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Aktau#Get_in) a [train](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Beyneu/Aktau) to [Aktau](http://www.marksmayo.com/2012/06/29/the-adventure-that-is-obshi-class-train-travel/) that will set you back 20-30$

According to [Caravanistan](http://caravanistan.com/transport/train/kazakhstan/), there are shared taxis that will take you there too, for about 500 tenge, though from my searching around everyone seems to take the train there and there is little mention, if any, of marshrutkas and taxis to Aktau.

Comment: You didn't quote from Mark's blog? No bounty for you. :P

Comment: @JoErNanO haha, careless answerer aren't I

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are Taxis for 5000 tenge, taking 5 hours. They do try to charge foreigners 50000 though - just get into the car and automatically hand over 5000